# Understanding FBSession and why they don't work as expected FB sdk for IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am using FB sdk for iOS (3.9).

So, following the tutorial from Facebook Developers, I am having in my AppDelegate the following check.

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
        // To-do, show logged in view
        NSLog(@"There is token for session");
    } else {
        // No, display the login page.
        NSLog(@"There isn't token for session");

}
```

When I relaunch my app, after I have requested permissions in the first launch, I can see that there is a token, as expected.

But in my next sreens, If I call this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        NSLog(@"FBSession is open. Will populate user details.");
        [self populateUserDetails];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Session is not open");
    }
```

Then I see the `Session is not open`.

in order to make it work I have to change my delegate function to that:

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
            // To-do, show logged in view
            NSLog(@"There is token for session");
            [self openSession]
        } else {
            // No, display the login page.
            NSLog(@"There isn't token for session");

    }
```

So, do I have to explicitly open the session every time? I thought that the session does not expire once you exit your app.

Can you explain in more details because I cannot get it from the facebook developers site.